# Rspec ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have rspec test for nested object (comment), it is nested in posts object. Here is the routes.rb:

```
  use_doorkeeper

  resources :posts do
    resources :comments 
  end

  root "posts#index"
end
```

Here is part of comments controller:

```
 class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_comment, only: [:destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:destroy]

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params['post_id'])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :comment, :user_id, :best, :file))
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post) }
      format.js
    end
  end
  private

  def find_comment
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

And here is rspec test:

```
 require 'rails_helper'

    RSpec.describe CommentsController, type: :controller do
      let(:user) { create(:user) }
      let(:post) { create(:post) }
    
      sign_in_user
    
      setup do
        allow(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
      end
    
      describe 'POST #create' do
        context 'with valid attributes' do
          let!(:posts) { post :create, params: { post_id: post, comment: attributes_for(:comment) } }
    
          it 'saves the new comment in the database' do
            expect {{ comment: attributes_for(:comment) } }.to change(Comment, :count).by(1)
          end
        end
      end
    
    end
```

Additional factory file for comments:

```
 FactoryBot.define do
  factory :comment do
    comment { 'Comment' }
    name { 'Name' }
    post
    user_id { create(:user).id }
  end
end
```

Macros to authorize user:

```
 module ControllerMacros
  def sign_in_user
    before do
      @user = create(:user)
      @request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      sign_in @user
    end
  end
end
```

So when I run spec test, I got this error:

```
 ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0)
```

What may be the problem, why can't I run CREATE rspec?

Comment: `change { Comment.count }.by(1)` does this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of things going on here. The error is because your `let(:post)` memoized helper is overriding the name of the `post` method. So, when you call `post :create ...` it is very unhappy. So, you just need to change the name of your memoized helper to something other than `:post`.

The second issue is your expectation will never pass:

```rb
expect {{ comment: attributes_for(:comment) } }.to change(Comment, :count).by(1)
```

When you use the `expect {}...to change()` form, RSpec literally checks that what's inside the `expect` block drives the specified change. In your case, the code inside the expect block doesn't create a Comment record in the database, it just returns a hash of attributes for a mock Comment so it will never pass. You do create a new Comment at the start of the context block, but it doesn't count since it's outside the `expect` block.

One way to fix that is to simply move the POST into the expect block:

```rb
RSpec.describe CommentsController, type: :controller do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:faux_post) { create(:post) } // Different name to avoid clash

  // ... stuff omitted
  
  describe 'POST #create' do
    context 'with valid attributes' do
      it 'saves the new comment in the database' do
        expect do
          post :create, params: { post_id: faux_post, comment: attributes_for(:comment) }
        end.to change(Comment, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```